# Using object's method as callback function for $.post

Tags: jquery

$.Comment = function() {
      this.alertme = "Alert!";
    }

```
$.Comment.prototype.send = function() {

  var self = this;
  $.post(
    self.url,
    {
      'somedata' : self.somedata
    },
    function(data, self) {
      self.callback(data);
    } 
  );

}

$.Comment.prototype.callback = function(data) {
  alert(this.alertme);
}
```

When I'm calling $.Comment.send() debugger is saying to me that `self.callback(data) is not a function`

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't want to declare `self` as an argument to the success function. If you remove that declaration, you'll pick up the local variable, which is what you want. E.g.:

```
$.Comment = function() {
    this.alertme = "Alert!";
}

$.Comment.prototype.send = function() {

    var self = this;
    $.post(
        self.url,
        {
            'somedata' : self.somedata
        },
        function(data) {         // <== removed `self` argument
            self.callback(data); // <== now sees `self` local var
        }
    );

}

$.Comment.prototype.callback = function(data) {
    alert(this.alertme);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not declare *self* as a parameter:

```
function(data) {
  self.callback(data);
}
```

That way *self* will be a closure and reference the correct object within the function.